google cloud function has 500ms of additional overhead that i cant trace
I've setup a google cloud function which takes less than 100ms to run (checked through cloud logging). However when i call the function it takes around 600ms. I dont think this is a cold boot issue as I'm running it in a tight loop (using benchmarkify).
I thought it might be related to calling it from a region that is far away, but I've setup another cloud function in the same region and it shows similar latency. Any idea what is causing the latency? This is just a normal firebase https v1 function in us-central region.
"2024-08-11T01:29:23.326906Z","benchmark0","Platform info:"
"2024-08-11T01:29:23.326970Z","benchmark0","=============="
"2024-08-11T01:29:23.327112Z","benchmark0","   Linux 4.4.0 x64"
"2024-08-11T01:29:23.327180Z","benchmark0","   Node.JS: 20.15.1"
"2024-08-11T01:29:23.327271Z","benchmark0","   V8: 11.3.244.8-node.23"
"2024-08-11T01:29:23.328138Z","benchmark0","   CPU: unknown × 2"
"2024-08-11T01:29:23.328690Z","benchmark0","   Memory: 1 GB"
"2024-08-11T01:29:23.328768Z","benchmark0",""
"2024-08-11T01:29:23.332129Z","benchmark0","Suite: octree.bin"
"2024-08-11T01:29:23.332281Z","benchmark0","================="
"2024-08-11T01:29:23.332367Z","benchmark0",""
"2024-08-11T01:29:23.332876Z","benchmark0","- Running 'A'..."
"2024-08-11T01:29:23.333353Z","benchmark0","querying 1"
"2024-08-11T01:29:24.482909Z","app","Function execution started"
"2024-08-11T01:29:24.708106Z","app","Function execution took 225 ms, finished with status code: 206"
"2024-08-11T01:29:24.746945Z","benchmark0","result"
"2024-08-11T01:29:24.747128Z","benchmark0","querying 2"
"2024-08-11T01:29:25.054992Z","app","Function execution started"
"2024-08-11T01:29:25.122878Z","app","Function execution took 67 ms, finished with status code: 206"
"2024-08-11T01:29:25.219459Z","benchmark0","result"
"2024-08-11T01:29:25.219596Z","benchmark0","querying 3"
"2024-08-11T01:29:25.364295Z","app","Function execution started"
"2024-08-11T01:29:25.506003Z","app","Function execution took 141 ms, finished with status code: 206"
"2024-08-11T01:29:25.523353Z","benchmark0","result"
"2024-08-11T01:29:25.523463Z","benchmark0","querying 4"
"2024-08-11T01:29:25.851368Z","app","Function execution started"
"2024-08-11T01:29:25.917669Z","app","Function execution took 66 ms, finished with status code: 206"
"2024-08-11T01:29:26.021476Z","benchmark0","result"
"2024-08-11T01:29:26.021624Z","benchmark0","querying 5"
"2024-08-11T01:29:26.267686Z","app","Function execution started"
"2024-08-11T01:29:26.342285Z","app","Function execution took 74 ms, finished with status code: 206"
"2024-08-11T01:29:26.420235Z","benchmark0","result"
"2024-08-11T01:29:26.932175Z","benchmark0","✔ A*            2 ops/sec"
"2024-08-11T01:29:26.932535Z","benchmark0",""
"2024-08-11T01:29:26.933566Z","benchmark0","   A* (#)       0%          (2 ops/sec)   (avg: 617ms)"
"2024-08-11T01:29:26.933774Z","benchmark0",""
"2024-08-11T01:29:26.934018Z","benchmark0","┌───┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐"
"2024-08-11T01:29:26.934206Z","benchmark0","│ A │ ██████████████████████████████████████████████████ │"
"2024-08-11T01:29:26.934268Z","benchmark0","└───┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘"
"2024-08-11T01:29:26.934459Z","benchmark0","-----------------------------------------------------------------------
"

Here's the stripped down function code:
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase-admin/app");

initializeApp();

app.get('/app/pointcloud/*/content/*', async (req, res) => {
    //Download stuff from firebase storage
})

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);

And the benchmark function:
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');
const Benchmarkify = require("benchmarkify");

functions.http('helloHttp', (req, res) => {

    const benchmark = new Benchmarkify().printHeader()

    var instance = 0

    // Create a test suite
    benchmark.createSuite("octree.bin", { time: 1000, minSamples: 5 })

        .ref("A", (done) => {
            instance += 1;
            console.log(`querying ${instance}`)
            const url = "https://myapp/app/pointcloud/xxx/content/octree.bin"
            fetch(url, {
                headers: {
                    "x-range": `bytes=${instance * 100000}-${(instance + 1) * 100000}`
                }
            }).then(() => {
                console.log('result')
                done()
            })
        });

    benchmark.run().then(result => console.log(result));

});


To put it briefly: You're not going to be able to trace every little bit of interaction between a client and server, unless you can somehow monitor the infrastructure between the two machines.  Especially not with serverless products, where the infra is automatically and opaquely maintained.  You can expect that every little abstraction between point A and point B is going to add some overhead.  To be honest, your numbers don't look bad to me.

Given that you haven't shown us everything you have deployed (including the full contents of all participating code, it's not clear what sort of answer you're expecting here.  Ideally you should provide all code and instructions on how to reproduce if you want some sort of detailed answer (or at least a guess).

@FloatingKiwi, I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.

As Answered by @guillaume blaquiere in the thread, it could be due to CPU configuration. I suggest you to increase the CPUs .

Note: 4Gb of memory = 2CPU @2.4Ghz, not 1 CPU (one thread) @4.8Ghz

Also as mentioned in this  article and document follow below points to improve the performance.

Use dependencies wisely

Because functions are stateless, the execution environment is often initialized from scratch (during what is known as a cold start). When a cold start occurs, the global context of the function is evaluated.
If your functions import modules, the load time for those modules can add to the invocation latency during a cold start. You can reduce this latency, as well as the time needed to deploy your function, by loading dependencies correctly and not loading dependencies your function doesn't use.


Use global variables to reuse objects in future invocations

There is no guarantee that the state of a Cloud Function will be preserved for future invocations. However, Cloud Functions often recycles the execution environment of a previous invocation. If you declare a variable in global scope, its value can be reused in subsequent invocations without having to be recomputed.


Do lazy initialization of global variables

If you initialize variables in global scope, the initialization code will always be executed via a cold start invocation, increasing your function's latency. In certain cases, this causes intermittent timeouts to the services being called if they are not handled appropriately in a try/catch block. If some objects are not used in all code paths, consider initializing them lazily on demand


Reduce cold starts by setting a minimum number of instances

By default, Cloud Functions scales the number of instances based on the number of incoming requests. You can change this default behavior by setting a minimum number of instances that Cloud Functions must keep ready to serve requests. Setting a minimum number of instances reduces cold starts of your application. We recommend setting a minimum number of instances if your application is latency-sensitive.



